# HTML Redirects to wrong

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

I am doing work for a client and I am beating my head against the wall trying to figure out what is happening on this site. First, he uses godaddy as his host and uses their express email marketing. One of the campaigns he was sending out had a wrong url in it. So that was easy enough to fix once I got logged in. Now, on the email that is sent out there is a link that says "To view this message as a printable PDF document, Click here." and it opens it up in the browser. NOW, I've tried finding the file it opens to change it with no luck. I've tried changing the html file in the directory it points to, but that does nothing and doesn't update the page. Any test page I create and try and open in a browser keeps the url but pulls in a different page (one in particular).

SO, as I've mentioned, in the email version of this, I've gotten it to work, just not in the browser version because I have no idea where it's pulling from or what is overwriting it.

Here is the link
http://nationalproduct.com/emailcampaigns/racing_stepmats/

At the bottom of this page there is a "Printable Version" button. This button should point to here:
/racing_stepmats/pdf/stepmats_racing.pdf#zoom=70

But instead points to here:
/regular_stepmats/pdf/stepmats_regular.pdf#zoom=70

I've also looked at the .htaccess file and there's only one line on there rewrite engine on so there's nothing in the .htaccess that's automatically loading or redirecting that I can see. Any wrong url that a user puts in doesn't go to a page not found, it just keeps what's been typed in the url bar but loads the racing rv mat page. ?:O

I've tried changing it in chrome and firefox in the developer tools and I know how to change the link to be correct, but I have no way of saving it from google or firefox to overwrite, that I know of at least. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: based on the link you have given us, I am going to make a guess and say this is not just HTML. What is the server side using? PHP, Ruby, Python, etc. Also, What Framework is being used in this application? CodeIgniter, Cake, Rails, Sinatra, Django?

Comment: I don't even know, I inherited a mess on the backend, there are so many files and folders on the hosting and server side I don't even know where to look. I know it's more than just html. How do I check what it is using? I haven't set it up to be using anything and I haven't found what's already set up. Hosting is through godaddy

Comment: It looks to be PHP; there are links in the source code that have `.php` file extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the support randak. Justin, I do know how to code in php, I've just never had to deal with someone else's mess and coding like this before as I've never had the need to make things do this. Your opinion is noted, however irrelevant it may be in this discussion, and people are able to learn things as they go, which is why I came here... to find answers, not be told how qualified I am or am not.

Comment: The owner has 15 different domains and was hosting this site, and all of it's content, in a subfolder. It was on the backend of godaddy where I found all the domains and where they were being hosted. Normally this would have been easier to find but there were hundreds of files and folders on the backend. Thanks for the pointers though ;) Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner has 15 different domains and was hosting this site, and all of it's content, in a subfolder. It was on the backend of godaddy where I found all the domains and where they were being hosted. Normally this would have been easier to find but there were hundreds of files and folders on the backend. Thanks for the pointers though ;) Fixed

Answer (score 0):

you just have to edit this part of the source of the page

```
<area shape="rect"
_mce_shape="rect"
coords="281,787,406,837"
_mce_coords="281,787,406,837"
href="http://nationalproduct.com/emailcampaigns/regular_stepmats/pdf/stepmats_regular.pdf#zoom=70"
_mce_href="http://nationalproduct.com/emailcampaigns/regular_stepmats/pdf/stepmats_regular.pdf#zoom=70">
```

replacing the wrong URL with the correct one

Comment: As I mentioned, I've tried changing the "index.html" file in the directory "/racing_stepmats" but with no luck. I can delete the thing and it doesn't make a difference. Yes, I've cleared my cookies and cahce before trying it again